# Internal frame ajustavel

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jinternalframe

Fiz um código simples no netbeans de um internalframe que carrega dentro do jframe, mas o internalframe fica num tamanho fixo.

Se eu abro ele com full screen **setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);**
Ele fica com um espação vazio

Se eu tento diminuir o tamanho da tela, ele corta um pedaço

Há um tempo atrás eu tinha feito esse mesmo código e ele ajustava automaticamente pelo tamanho da tela, alguém sabe como fazer isso de volta?

**# Jframe.java**

```
# Jframe.java

    package teste;

    public class jframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form jframe
     */
    public jframe() {
        initComponents();
        setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // iniciar com tela full
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jDesktopPane = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDesktopPaneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDesktopPane);
        jDesktopPane.setLayout(jDesktopPaneLayout);
        jDesktopPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDesktopPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 611, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jDesktopPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDesktopPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 322, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        jMenuItem1.setText("TESTE");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jDesktopPane)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                .addComponent(jDesktopPane))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        internalFrame internal = new internalFrame();
        jDesktopPane.add(internal);
        internal.setVisible(true);
    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new jframe().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**# InternalFrame.java**

```
# InternalFrame.java

    package teste;

    public class internalFrame extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form internalFrame
     */
    public internalFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");

        jButton3.setText("jButton3");

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jButton4.setText("jButton4");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 178, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 202, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 214, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 154, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 52, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: O que você quer ajustar afinal? Esse código foi gerado pelo netbeans e é dificil alterar alguma coisa nele.

Comment: Queria saber se tem alguma opção pra deixar o código responsivo, porque esse meu internalFrame fica zuado dentro do jFrame:
https://i.imgur.com/lykkMVk.png
https://i.imgur.com/YXyhV7w.png
2 pontos: Não está pegando a tela toda, e quando eu diminuo a tela ta cortando uma parte

Já esse aqui, ele fica fullscreen e se diminui ele redimensiona:
https://i.imgur.com/vvUPF0n.png
https://i.imgur.com/wRYrkZf.png

E os dois eu fiz de forma padrão.